# Can't select a column name containing accent

Tags: php, symfony, odbc, symfony5, adodb-php

## Problem

I'm actually on a new website project with Symfony 5.
As I have to access an historical database where all of our products details are stored, I have to use AdoDb so I can use odbc driver (As doctrine doesn't allow to use it).

When I try selecting a field with accent, the query failed and throw a [S0022](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/workaround-sybase-s0022-invalid-column-name-message-using-sql-rational-integration-tester) error code.
Full error message is :
`"[Simba][SQLEngine] (31750) Column not found: ar1_händlerpreis"`

See that `ar1_händlerpreis` contain a "ä" character which seems to be the problem.

## What I have already tried

Here is my code for the query.
Look at the `ar1_händlerpreis` which is present into the "Prepare" function first parameter.

```
$strIn = "";// Adodb odbc doesn't support IN(?) with an array parameter (string are quoted automatically)
            foreach ($array_article_number as $number) {
                $strIn .= "?,";
            }
            $strIn = substr($strIn, 0, -1); // Last one doesn't need ',' characters as it's the last one.

$query = $this->_db->Prepare("SELECT ar1_artikelnummer, ar2_mwststeuerschl, ar1_bestand, ar1_klassifizierung, ar1_bezeichnung3, ar1_apothekenpreis, ar1_händlerpreis AS apreis FROM artikeldaten WHERE ar1_artikelnummer IN(" . $strIn . ")");
$datas = $this->_db->Execute($query, $array_article_number);
```

I have try to edit the field ar1_händlerpreis in my query string as :

- ar1_h[ä]ndlerpreis (As told [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-using-special-characters#workaround))
- `ar1_händlerpreis` (Surrounding with backstick ... Since I know that some fields need to be escaped)
- ar1_händlerpreis || '' (As explain [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/workaround-sybase-s0022-invalid-column-name-message-using-sql-rational-integration-tester) it may have convert the column name to an expression an should not generate error)
- ar1_händlerpreis + 0 (Same as [previous one](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/workaround-sybase-s0022-invalid-column-name-message-using-sql-rational-integration-tester), it may have been converted to an expression)

I have also tried to change encoding character for accessing database :

- `$this->_db->setConnectionParameter('CharacterSet','UTF-8');` (As explain [here](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:setcharset))

But nothing do...

## Some code

I provide you more code to see if i did something wrong.

This is my ADOdbConnection Service which i use when i need to connect to the historical database.
Most of the time, i use Doctrine for the website specific database.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use ADOConnection;

class ADOdbConnection
{
    private ADOConnection $_db;
    /**
     * AdodbConnection constructor.
     * @param $host
     * @param $user
     * @param $pwd
     * @param $db_name
     */
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name)
    {
        $this->_db = ADONewConnection('odbc');
        $this->_db->setConnectionParameter('CharacterSet','UTF-8');
        $this->_db->connect('DRIVER={CONZEPT 16 ODBC-Treiber (64 bit)};SERVER='.$host.';DB='.$db_name.';', $user, $pwd, $db_name);
    }

    public function getDb() : ADOConnection{
        return $this->_db;
    }

}
```

It work as it should, doing a connection to the database.

Then, this is my DAL for the product (Article) table :

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\DAL_w2;

use ADOConnection;
use App\Services\ADOdbConnection;

class ArticleDal
{

    private ADOConnection $_db;

    public function __construct(ADOdbConnection $ADOdbConnection)
    {
        $this->_db = $ADOdbConnection->getDb();
        $this->_db->setCharset('UTF-8');
        $this->_db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Join w2 database for every article number given
     * @param array $array_article_number An array of article number.
     * @return array|null An array of article from w2 article's table or null
     */
    public function getDataForListArticleFromArticleNumber(array $array_article_number): ?array
    {
        $res = null;
        if (count($array_article_number)) {
            $strIn = "";// Adodb doesn't support IN(?) with an array parameter (string are quoted automatically)
            foreach ($array_article_number as $number) {
                $strIn .= "?,";
            }
            $strIn = substr($strIn, 0, -1); // Last one doesn't need ',' characters as it's the last one.
            $query = $this->_db->Prepare("SELECT ar1_artikelnummer, ar2_mwststeuerschl, ar1_bestand, ar1_klassifizierung, ar1_bezeichnung3, ar1_apothekenpreis, ar1_händlerpreis + 0 AS apreis FROM artikeldaten WHERE ar1_artikelnummer IN(" . $strIn . ")");
            dump($query);
            $datas = $this->_db->Execute($query, $array_article_number);
            dump($this->_db->_errorCode);
            dump($this->_db->_errorMsg);
            dump($datas);
            die();
            // Assign article number as array key
            $res = array();
            foreach ($datas as $article_data) {
                $res[$article_data['ar1_artikelnummer']] = $article_data;
            }
        }
        $res = $res ?: null; // If we don't have any data
        return $res;
    }

}
```

This code display the following result :

> ArticleDal.php on line 37: "SELECT ar1_artikelnummer,
> ar2_mwststeuerschl, ar1_bestand, ar1_klassifizierung,
> ar1_bezeichnung3, ar1_apothekenpreis, ar1_händlerpreis + 0 AS apreis
> FROM artikeldaten WHERE ar1_artikelnummer
> IN(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) "

> ArticleDal.php on line 39: "S0022"

> ArticleDal.php on line 40: "[Simba][SQLEngine] (31750) Column not
> found: ar1_händlerpreis"

> ArticleDal.php on line 41: false

And there is an example of what return a `SELECT *` (I truncate it because it have 360 columns...) :

```
 0 => array:360 [▼
    "ar1_artikelnummer" => "0002446"
...
   "ar1_preislistenartik" => "0"
    "ar1_preislistenpreis" => "0"
    b"ar1_preislistenänder" => null
    "ar1_preislistenprneu" => "0"
    "ar1_preislistenneuab" => null
    "ar1_collianz" => "1"
    "ar1_tiefstpreis_brut" => "0"
    "ar1_ean_nummer" => ""
    "ar1_faxpreislistenar" => "0"
    "ar1_inetrnetartikel" => "0"
    "ar1_unterwarengruppe" => "1"
    "ar1_verbot_in_stl" => "1"
    "ar1_apothekenpreis" => "5.82"
    b"ar1_händlerpreis" => "3.77"
...
```

It's weird those little 'b' in front of field with accent (For ar1_händlerpreis and ar1_preislistenänder). [dump()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#the-dump-function) is the debug function from Symfony framework.

If i use var_dump instead of dump, i got this result :

```
["ar1_h�ndlerpreis"]=> string(4) "3.77"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do a `SELECT *` first, and then check what you _actually_ get the column name back as, when you then fetch the results …?

Comment: try surrounding them in backtics ` ` `

Comment: I have already try surrounding them with backstick as i say in my question, but stackoverflow convert this into code format so you can't know... Editing my question

Comment: @CBroe I edit my question to provide you the result of a ```SELECT *```

Comment: Is that from a var_dump, or some framework-specific debug function? Try and loop over it using foreach, and output the keys with `urlencode` - that’ll help see what the actual byte values used are.

Comment: @CBroe It's a debug function from symfony framework, it is not modifying content.
See doc about it : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#the-dump-function (I have edit my question with var_dump)

Comment: The `�` is a byte (or byte sequence), that can not be interpreted correctly in the character encoding your output page uses. Again, loop over that array and output the keys with `urlencode`, the percent encoding in that place will show you what the byte value actually is.

Comment: I assume, you're gonna introduce a new quoting strategy for your column names to include German accents ... https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Comment: @Jakumi I do not use doctrine for this db as i say

Comment: oh. my bad. well then it's just encoding, file encoding could be fun too ;o)

Comment: @CBroe I got this : ```ar1_h%E4ndlerpreis```!!
But... But what good does it do me

Comment: Try and insert the “opposite” of that operation into your query then for the column name, `urldecode('ar1_h%E4ndlerpreis')`

Comment: @CBroe Gosh ! it worked.

So this is my final query : 
```$query = $this->_db->Prepare("SELECT ar1_artikelnummer, ar2_mwststeuerschl, ar1_bestand, ar1_klassifizierung, ar1_bezeichnung3, ar1_apothekenpreis, " . urldecode('ar1_h%E4ndlerpreis') . " AS ar1_händlerpreis FROM artikeldaten WHERE ar1_artikelnummer IN(" . $strIn . ")");```
Thanks to the alias i can access it without any problems.